# Why non surjective polynomial map between $A^n$ and $A^m$ demand image closed algebraic set?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $f_i\in C[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ with $i\leq m$. Suppose $f_i$ are algebraically independent functions. Consider the map $\phi:A^n\to A^m$ by $\phi(x_1,\dots, x_n)=(f_i(x_1,\dots, x_n))_i$. Suppose $\phi$ is non surjection. Then $Im(\phi)$ is closed algebraic subset of $A^n$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Why is $Im(\phi)$ a closed subset if $\phi$ is not surjection? I could imagine $A^2\to A^2$ by $(x,y)\to (x,xy)$. Clearly $x,xy$ are algebraically independent. Furhtermore, the map is not surjection as part of $x=0$ axis is missing. It is worse that the image is not closed algebraic set. Have I misunderstood the statement?

Context: The book tries to explain $f_i$ algebraic independence/essential parameters is equivalent to surjectivity of the map $\phi$ above.

Ref. Beltrametti M.C., et al. - Lectures on curves, surfaces and projective varieties Sec 3.2 of Chpt 3, Pg 62

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an error in the text.  You are correct that the image of $\varphi$ need not be closed.  The result being proved (that $\varphi$ is surjective iff the $f_i$ are algebraically independent) is simply wrong, as your example also shows.  The correct statement is that $\varphi$ is *dominant* (has dense image) iff the $f_i$ are algebraically independent.

Comment: Ah in that case, it seems very reasonable.